# Configure one-to-one relationship with EF Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So I want a one-to-one relationship between `Person` and `Category`.

1. `Person` must have `Category` (FK).
2. Deleting `Category` will throw Exception if some of the `CategoryID` still exists in `Person` table.

How to achieve this with EF FluentAPI?

My current code :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasKey(pk => pk.PersonID)
            .HasRequired(r => r.CategoryID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this MSDN documentation on [creating relationships with FluentAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#UniDirectional)

Since the navigation property is only defined on the person object you would go with this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.Category) 
    .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
public class Person
{
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
   public int CategoryID { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }

   public virtual Person Person{ get; set; }
}
```

and with fluent api :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Category)
            .WithOptional(c => c.Person)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
```

Comment: will this create PersonID as PK?

Comment: in this case you mus first add category , then insert person. value of PersonId must equal with value of CategoryId.